# Is this doubly linked list method, correct? (Remove)

Tags: javascript, algorithm, doubly-linked-list

```
remove(range){
    if(range === 0){
        return this.shift();
    }
    else if(range == this.length){
        return this.pop();
    }
    else if(range < 0 || range > this.length ){
        return undefined
    }
    else{
        const temp = this.get(range);
        const after = temp.next;
        const before = temp.prev;
        before.next = after;
        after.prev = before;
        temp.next = null;
        temp.prev = null;
        this.length--;
        return temp;
        
    }
}
```

I wrote this method for `remove` in a doubly linked list, it works, but I'm not sure if it's correct overall.

Comment: so, the valid range of the value `range` is `0` to `this.length` inclusive? so, the last entry in the list can be removed using `remove(length)` OR `remove(length-1)`

Comment: Currently this code should throw a null-reference exception on `after.prev = ...` for `remove(length-1)`.

Comment: Write some tests. You can prove this correct

Answer (score 0):

There is essentially one issue:

The index of the last node in a linked list is not `this.length` but `this.length - 1`. For example, if a linked list has two nodes, its length is 2, and the nodes have indices 0 and 1.

So this part of the code:

```
    else if(range == this.length){
        return this.pop();
    }
    else if(range < 0 || range > this.length ){
        return undefined
    }
```

Should be changed to:

```
    else if(range == this.length - 1){
//                              ^^^^
        return this.pop();
    }
    else if(range < 0 || range >= this.length ){
//                             ^^
        return undefined
    }
```

Not a problem, but the name [range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_%28computer_programming%29) is not well chosen as it suggests a *pair*:

> For example, the *range* of a signed 16-bit integer variable is all the integers from −32,768 to +32,767.

As in your case this parameter is a single integer denoting the 0-based position of the targeted node, the name `index` should be preferred.